# Change Uri/Id of a team project?

Tags: tfs

We're in the process of moving our source code from TFVC to Git, and when doing that we would like to "start fresh" by moving to a new Project Collection. We would like to keep our work items though, so the idea was to

1. Create a copy of the original Collection
2. Use TFS built-in cloning function to assure that the new Collection becomes a copy
3. Remove all but the current team project from the copy, getting rid of "old junk"
4. Transfer (most of) source code from TFVC to Git here, for the current Project only.
5. (When everything's been verified) remove TFVC source from the "new" Project.

The idea was to have the original Collection available as read-only for most users for reference, safe-keeping, etc. All of the work items and code that would be deleted from the new copy would be quite easily available but still kept separate.

This, however fails for one reason right now: TFS cloning function only works on Collection level, not on team Projects. So the "new" team Project uses the same Id/Uri as the old one (I've checked), and the new Collection cannot be Active/started at the same time as the old one; we get the error message

```
TF253021: A team Project with ProjectUri <....> is duplicated in at least two Projects ...
```

So, is it possible to change the Uri/Id of a team Project somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change the project ID.

You have to follow the error info suggested:

> The collection cannot start while the duplication exists. **You must
>   delete this project from all but one of the collections before the
>   collection can be started.**

Otherwise, the new Collection cannot be Active/started at the same time as the old one. More details please take a look at this related blog: **[Can’t keep cloned projects in both collections (original and cloned)](http://mohamedradwan.com/2014/03/13/cant-keep-cloned-projects-in-both-collections-original-and-cloned/)**